# generate list of dates between 2 dates and save list in database

Tags: php, dynamic, mysqli, insert

I would like a bit of help with an issue I'm currently having.  I need to generate a list of dates using the first and last date in the list and then save the list of dates generated in a database table.  What is the best way to do this?

My code so far:

```
<?php

    $apartment = (isset($_POST['apartment']) ? $_POST['apartment'] : null);
    $name = (isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null);
    $surname = (isset($_POST['surname']) ? $_POST['surname'] : null);
    $email = (isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null);
    $address = (isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : null);
    $mobile = (isset($_POST['mobile']) ? $_POST['mobile'] : null);
    $pax = (isset($_POST['pax']) ? $_POST['pax'] : null);
    $address = (isset($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : null);
    $remarks = (isset($_POST['remarks']) ? $_POST['remarks'] : null);
    $day_from = (isset($_POST['day_from']) ? $_POST['day_from'] : null);
    $month_from = (isset($_POST['month_from']) ? $_POST['month_from'] : null);
    $year_from = (isset($_POST['year_from']) ? $_POST['year_from'] : null);
    $booking_from = $year_from."-".$month_from."-".$day_from;
    $day_to = (isset($_POST['day_to']) ? $_POST['day_to'] : null);
    $month_to = (isset($_POST['month_to']) ? $_POST['month_to'] : null);
    $year_to = (isset($_POST['year_to']) ? $_POST['year_to'] : null);
    $booking_to = $year_to."-".$month_to."-".$day_to;
    $no_of_nights = abs(strtotime($booking_to) - strtotime($booking_from));     
    $days = floor($no_of_nights / (60*60*24));

   include 'connect.php';

 if (!$conn->autocommit(FALSE)) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }

 if (!$conn->query("INSERT INTO client_details (clientID, name, email, address, mobile) VALUES ('', '$name $surname', '$email', '$address', '$mobile')")) {
     printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }

 if (!$conn->query("INSERT INTO bookings (bookingID, apartmentID, clientID, date_from, date_to, nights, pax, remarks) VALUES ('', '$apartment', LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$booking_from', '$booking_to', '$days', '$pax', '$remarks')")) {
     printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }

function dateArray($booking_from, $booking_to) {
    echo "yo";

    $aryRange = array();

     $iDateFrom=mktime(1,0,0,substr($booking_from,5,2),     substr($booking_from,8,2),substr($booking_from,0,4));
    $iDateTo=mktime(1,0,0,substr($booking_to,5,2),     substr($booking_to,8,2),substr($booking_to,0,4));

if ($iDateTo>=$iDateFrom) {
    array_push($aryRange, date('Y-m-d', $iDateFrom));
    {
        while ($iDateFrom<$iDateTo)
        {
            $iDateFrom+=86400; // add 24 hours
        array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
        }
    }
    return $aryRange;
    }



dateArray($booking_from, $booking_to);

  if (!$conn->query("INSERT INTO room_nights (bookingID, apartmentID, dates) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$apartment', '$dates['dates']')")) {
     printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }


 if (!$conn->commit()) {
     printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }
 $conn->close();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution to the question.

> Step1: Create an array with the dates
>   Step2: Loop through the array and insert the dates in the database table;

```
<?php
$day_from = (isset($_POST['day_from']) ? $_POST['day_from'] : null);
$month_from = (isset($_POST['month_from']) ? $_POST['month_from'] : null);
$year_from = (isset($_POST['year_from']) ? $_POST['year_from'] : null);
$booking_from = $year_from."-".$month_from."-".$day_from;
$day_to = (isset($_POST['day_to']) ? $_POST['day_to'] : null);
$month_to = (isset($_POST['month_to']) ? $_POST['month_to'] : null);
$year_to = (isset($_POST['year_to']) ? $_POST['year_to'] : null);
$booking_to = $year_to."-".$month_to."-".$day_to;
$no_of_nights = abs(strtotime($booking_to) - strtotime($booking_from));     
$days = floor($no_of_nights / (60*60*24));

// create array with dates 
function daterange($booking_from, $booking_to, $step = '+1 day', $output_format = 'Y-m-d') {
 $dates = array();
 $first = new DateTime($booking_from);
 $last = new DateTime($booking_to);
 $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($step);
 $period = new DatePeriod($first, $interval, $last);

 foreach ($period as $date) {
  $dates[] = $date->format($output_format);
  }

   return $dates;
 }

 $dates = daterange($booking_from, $booking_to);

  print_r($dates);

  include 'connect.php';

  if (!$conn->autocommit(FALSE)) {
  printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
  }

  // loop thru dates and save in database table
  foreach ($dates as $date) {
  if (!$conn->query("INSERT INTO room_nights (bookingID, apartmentID, dates) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$apartment', '$date')")) {
  printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
 }
   }

 if (!$conn->commit()) {
 printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $conn->error);
}
$conn->close();

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason to get this error is that you call the function `daterange` without saving the result that it returns. So instead of calling it this way:

```
daterange($booking_from, $booking_to, $step = '+1 day', $output_format = 'y-m-d');
```

You should add the `$dates` variable to store the returned result of the function and to use it afterwards.

```
$dates = daterange($booking_from, $booking_to, $step = '+1 day', $output_format = 'y-m-d');
```

**EDIT:**

The following code:

```
<?php    
function daterange($booking_from, $booking_to, $step = '+1 day', $output_format = 'Y-m-d') {
      $dates = array();
      $first = strtotime($booking_from);
      $last = strtotime($booking_to);

      while ($first <= $last) {
        $dates[] = date($output_format, $first);
        $first = strtotime($step, $first);
      }

      return $dates;
    }

    $dates = daterange('2015-08-01', '2015-08-10');

    print_r($dates);
?>
```

returns an array of dates which is stored in the `$dates` param:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-08-01
    [1] => 2015-08-02
    [2] => 2015-08-03
    [3] => 2015-08-04
    [4] => 2015-08-05
    [5] => 2015-08-06
    [6] => 2015-08-07
    [7] => 2015-08-08
    [8] => 2015-08-09
    [9] => 2015-08-10
)
```

[Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8836e19c099bf9157f7bf76c2af3cdbe8e9166e1) is a sandbox where you can see the result.

Please take a note here that the $output_format shold be `'Y-m-d'` in order to get the date in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

You can not store an Array into a DATE field. Even if you want to store an Array, you should use the PHP's `serialize` function and store it in a BLOB field in the database. ([See the documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php))

So if you want to store the date range you are going to need at least two fields in the DB, e.g. `date_from` and `date_to`. In this case the INSERT statement should look like this:

```
$conn->query("INSERT INTO room_nights (bookingID, apartmentID, date_from, date_to) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$apartment', '$dates[0]', '". $dates[count($dates) - 1] ."')");
```

P.s. Also I saw that you are converting the `$booking_from` and `$booking_to` params multiple times from string to date - once before the `daterange` function definition and once in the very same function.

Comment: Tried that - howeverI'm getting an error stating Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDevelopment\V18\insertdata.php on line 52 (in the sql)

Comment: Well it seems that there are more than one issues.

First I want to point out that it's not necessary to pass `$step` and `$output_format` variables as they are the same with the default ones in the function (http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default).

After that in the `daterange` function you are creating and returning actually an array which you try to insert into the table. That's why you get this notice. What data type is the field `dates` in the DB and what do you want actually to insert in it?

Comment: The data type of dates is date ie yyyy-mm-dd. And I would like to insert the range of dates generated in the array.

Comment: Thanks for the help however the result in the table is not as expected/ desired.  I would like all the dates to be stored, and not only the first and last one.